# Injective uniformly continuous function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, continuity

We say that a function $f: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ is *uniformly continuous* if there is an integer $K\geq 1$ such that
 whenever $(x,y),(x',y')\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ with $|(x,y)-(x',y')| = 1$ in the Euclidean distance, then $|f(x,y)-f(x',y')| < K$.

Is there an injective uniformly continuous function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: This is not what's usually called "uniformly continuous". In this precise setting (functions from $\mathbf{Z}^k$ to any metric space), this is just "Lipschitz". In the usual definition, every function from a uniformly discrete metric space to any metric space is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. A uniformly continuous function takes $O(N)$ distinct values on an $N\times N$ grid.